# How do I restructure RAID 10?

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm, dd

We would like to alter the partition without losing data. Here is the sketch of the plan. I am wondering if it is doable using mdadm; and if so, please kindly point some reference on how to carry out the following steps.

For RAID 10, there are four disks used.

```
(1 2)(3 4)
```

The idea is to work on 1 and 3 while keeping 2 and 4 as backup.

```
1: break RAID 10 into two arrays of RAID 0 => (1 3) (2 4)    (How?)
2: re-partition and format (1 3)
3: copy data from (2 4) to (1 3)
4: re-partition and format (2 4) exactly as (1 3) 
5: join (2 4) with (1 3) to form RAID 10  (How?)
```

Does it sound doable? Thanks a lot!

Add:

It looks like this [guy (drumfile)](https://superuser.com/a/366500/252532) is doing something similar, but lack of enough detail.

Comment: You probably might want to have a look at [ZFS](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native) or BTRFS. Because at least with ZFS this would very easy (if `autoexpand` was set on the pool) as you could just remove the mirrors for the drive, increase their size, re-add the mirrors, resilver and so forth. Though ZFS best practices recommend not to manually partition a drive and also you cannot shrink a pool (but you can remove mirrors and spares, of course).

Comment: Also as user *No Time* pointed out in his answer, you should have a backup of the data on the RAID set. A backup is defined by having at least 3 copies of the data on different devices and possibly on different media and also possibly in different locations. 1 RAID set with no matter how much redundancy in the set still counts as 1 copy. If the set breaks or the data (of filesystems) on there gets somehow corrupted, then your data is gone.

Comment: Do you mean steps the manually fail and remove a drive? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID#Removing_Devices_from_an_Array

Comment: I think it should be fail-remove. Originally, I think just to stop md and restart it with two "missing"? Will it work too?

Comment: @LiveWireBT, BTW, your link is quite helpful. I guess I can start experimenting from there.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot recommend one over the other. Both are risky, when you have no backup and I have not much experience with `mdadm`.

Comment: *Why* do you want to reformat?  What is it about the existing array do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this, so take it with a grain of salt (wait for other better answers).
I am not sure you can break this apart with no risk of data loss, so there should be some backup involved no matter what. If you are breaking a logical volume, you **WILL** have data loss.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

This shows software raid with mdadm.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Shows similar as above but uses LVM as well, which you would use with (1 3) and (2 4) 2 separate logical volumes over 4 disks.

I don't see a way around backing up your data on another medium unless your disks are not full (and would fit on one), if this is the case, set up disk 1 take the backup from (3 4) move all of it onto disk 1, format (2 4), move data from 1 -> (2 4), format (1 3). You would have both "sets" LVM (spread across), but honestly it seems like it would be better just to do 2 RAID 10's.

I hope this helps in or can lead to a better answer.